# Delphi's convert.exe as a git diff driver?

Tags: git, delphi

I need to check some Delphi files (*.dfm) into a git repository in binary form, but would still like to be able to see file differences as text. I've got the .gitconfig and .gitattributes file worked out such that I can have it run an arbitrary bash script or exe when doing the diff...

However, I can't figure out if git expects this to convert temp files in-place, if it wants to see the text on stdout, or what. The exe is rather bare-bones:

```
Delphi Form Conversion Utility Version 7.0
Copyright (c) 1995,2002 Borland Software Corporation
Usage: convert.exe [-i] [-s] [-t | -b] <filespec(s) | @filelist>
  -i  Convert files in-place (output overwrites input)
  -s  Recurse subdirectories
  -t  Convert to text
  -b  Convert to binary
```

If `-i` is omitted, it creates another .txt file in the same folder.

How can I make use of this and get sane results?

Comment: Kinda odd that you wouldn't just use text dfm files

Comment: *I need to check some Delphi files (*.dfm) into a git repository in binary form,.....* Why is that? You do know that you can save `.dfm` files as text, do you?

Comment: @TomBrunberg Yeh. And I know when they're in txt form, the project only compiles 1 time in 50, with linker errors the rest. In binary, it'll work every time. But there are enough dfms messed up (out of 2500) by the conversion process that it becomes difficult to check changes into git. Would like to check them in as binary, once, and avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention whether you are talking about using `textconv` or external diff.

A `textconv` program is expected to act as a file-filter: it must read the file named via a single argument, and write text to stdout.  Git will then run the program twice, once for each of the two binary inputs, and save the program's output—possibly only "just now", or possibly for an indeterminate length of time—and will produce, as the `git diff` output, a diff between the output from the two runs of the `textconv` program.

To allow Git to *cache* the `textconv` result (to speed up a future diff), add `cachetextconv = true` as described in [the gitattributes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes).

If you're talking about external diff drivers, they're invoked with *seven* (!) arguments (technically, *up to* 7).  See the same documentation, which then refers to the (brief) `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` description in [the top level `git` command documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git).  These seven parameters include the names of two temporary files that contain the file contents to be compared.

[edits]

In the global gitconfig file, you'd add something like the following:

```
[diff "dfm"]
        textconv = U:/dfmconverter.sh
        cachetextconv = true
```

In your git attributes file, something like this:

```
*.dfm        diff=dfm
```

And then for the script itself:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    conv() {
            x=`basename "$1" .dfm`
            y=`dirname "$1"`
            /c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Borland/Delphi7/Bin/convert -t $1 1>>/dev/null
            cat $y/$x.txt
            rm $y/$x.txt
    }

    conv $1
```

These definitely need the output of the conversion on stdout. Borland's convert.exe also spams up with some credit/copyright thing, and doesn't bother to have a --quiet option. Might be able to leave it in, but I wasn't sure if it was always the same. dirname works weirdly on Windows without double quotes around the path, but you need that because the current change might be in place, but the compared version is spooled out to $LOCALAPPDATA, and it's just easier to capture the dir out of the path supplied in $1 and reuse it.

All of this gets diffs to work on the command-line, but if there's a way to do it for TortoiseGit, I've yet to stumble across it.

Comment: I'd prefer it as a file filter. It's not a proper diff utility itself. It only converts.

Comment: OK, so to use it as a textconv program, you will need to write your own tiny program: use the (single) argument as the input file. Copy that to a disposable temporary file in case it's the original data, and convert in place—or, using the "creates a .txt", maneuver to somewhere where it's safe to create a temporary file, make a link or symbolic link if needed so that the supplied program behaves, and convert to .txt output. Then, read the resulting file and write that data to stdout. Finally, clean up all temporaries.

Comment: @torek you should make this an answer. It's exactly what the OP needs to do.

Comment: @dummzeuch: but that would require that I write the script, and I don't even have the program in question. :-)

Comment: @torek Thanks. Using dirname was fun in git bash... would only give me a C: unless the path was wrapped in double quotes. Ugh. But cat-ing out the contents of the txt, then removing it... I've gotten this to work on the command line at least. Next up is Tortoise Git and Gitlab (coworkers use the former, and everyone uses the latter).

Comment: @JohnO: you might want to move your sample code to an answer of your own, which you can then accept. If this were my script I'd worry about possibly clobbering a `.txt` file in the `$y` directory, wherever that may be; I'd probably have used `mktemp -d` to make a temp dir of my own (along with `trap` to clean up if interrupted). But I don't have Windows in the first place, so I'm not sure what constraints there are.

Comment: Wanted you to get the shiny internet points, no need for my own answer. In a delphi project I don't think anyone should need to worry about clobbering txt files of the same name but different extension as their source files, but if so they can implement the fancier way you suggest... "left as an exercise for the reader".